# Geckofx60.64 -Version 60.0.26 Not Working In Another PC

Tags: c#, geckofx

I made a browser with geckofx with the below code, its working in my pc where i build it but it is not working in any my office pc not sure why. Our office pc is win 8 64 bit.

When I try to open the .exe file nothing is happening.

```
public Form1()
        {

            InitializeComponent();
            Xpcom.Initialize("Firefox64");
            geckoWebBrowser.Navigate("https://google.com");
        }
```

---

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Check your windows event log for errors.  Make sure all of the DLLs are present.  Make sure the target PC has the right framework installed.

Comment: Okay. I will look into it tomorrow and get back.